# Why doesn't the following statement work?

Tags: c++, c

Today I gave a test there was the following question written and because I am new to C++, I became confused to the following question.

Why doesn't the following statement work?

```
char str[ ] = "Hello" ;
strcat ( str, '!' ) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char str[] = "Hello";
strcat (str, '!') ;
```

`strcat` second argument must be a pointer to a string, but you are passing a character constant.

The correct call would be `strcat(str, "!");` (note the `"` instead of the `'`) but you also need to reserve enough space in `str` which is only large enough to hold the `"Hello"` string. For example, for your test, you can reserve more bytes with `char str[64] = "Hello";`

Answer (score 1):

`strcat()` calls for pointer for both arguments.

`'!'` will converted to an (invalid for many chance) pointer by implementation-defined manner, then the program may crash for Segmentation Fault.

Note that

```
char str[ ] = "Hello" ;
strcat ( str, "!" ) ;
```

won't work well either due to lack of buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[ ] = "Hello" ;
strcat ( str, '!' ) ;
              ^^^ --- this is of type char
```

strcat signature is :

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so, second parameter is of type `const char*` and not `char`. You must pass either string literal or variable of type `const char*`. Actually string literals are of type `const char[]` but they decay to `const char*` when being assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` function expects two strings.`'!'` is a character.
in order to concatenate safely,your array must be big enough to hold the other string,so change `'!'` to `"!"`,and `str[]` to `str[8]` or more.

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[20] = "Hello" ;
    strcat ( str, "!" ) ;
    printf("%s\n",str);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. The immediate issue is that the second parameter must be a `const char*`. `strcat` reads the memory starting at that location, until the `\0` is reached. If no `\0` can be reached then the function behaviour is undefined.
2. It's up to you to make sure that `str` is large enough to receive the concatenated string. If not, then the behaviour is undefined.

On the second point, you can write something like `char str[100] = "Hello";` That will reserve 100 bytes of memory, populating the first 6 elements with `Hello\0`.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you decide that these statements

```
char str[ ] = "Hello" ;
strcat ( str, '!' ) ;
```

do not work?:)

All depends on how the function `strcat` is defined.

For example it can be defined the following way

```
char * strcat( char *s, char c )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( s );
    if ( n ) s[n-1] = c;

    return s;
}
```

Or the following way

```
char * strcat( char *s, char c )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( s );
    char *t = new char[n + 2];

    std::strcpy( t, s );

    t[ n - 2 ] = c;
    t[ n - 1 ] = '\0';

    return t;
}
```

If `strcat` in your  example is the standard C function `std::strcat` then again it does not mean that the statements will not work. It means that the program with such statements will not compile because the second argument has a wrong type.

But if you specify a correct value for the second argument like this

```
strcat ( str, "!" ) ;
```

that is using a string literal instead of the character literal then indeed the statements will not work as you are expecting because array `str` does not have enough space to append string literal `"!"`.

The array should be defined at least like

```
char str[7] = "Hello" ;
        ^^^
```

and the function should be called like

```
strcat ( str, "!" ) ;
              ^^^
```